# Prove $AC$ is parallel to $B_1D_1$ in a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

In a cyclic quadrilateral, $ABCD$,  consider $DD_1$ perpendicular to $DC$ with $D_1$ on the line $AB$, $BB_1$ perpendicular to $AB$ with $B_1$ on line $DC$. Prove $AC$ is parallel to $B_1D_1$.

I'm not to sure how to prove this or even draw the starting diagram (I'm very new to geometry).

Comment: @rae306 But there is the orthogonality condition.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It is clear that the quadrilateral $DD_1BB_1$ is also cyclic since its opposite angles are supplementary (they add up to $180^{\circ}$). Let's call the circumcircle of the quadrilateral $ABCD$ as $\mathscr{C}$ and that of $DD_1BB_1$ as $\mathscr{C}_1$.

Let's also draw the diagonal $BD$. Now, the chord $DA$ of circle $\mathscr{C}$ subtends the same angle at points $C$ and $B$ (it is the property of any circle that the inscribed angles subtended by the same arc are equal). Thus, $$\angle ABD = \angle ACD$$ Similarly, the chord $DD_1$ of circle $\mathscr{C}_1$ subtends the same angle at points $B_1$ and $B$. Thus, $$\angle D_1BD =\angle D_1B_1D$$
From these two relations, $\angle ACD = \angle D_1B_1D$. These angles are the corresponding angles of the line segment $B_1D$, rendering $AC || B_1D_1$.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to deal with the case $AB \parallel CD$ first. Then, for the case $AB \nparallel CD$, the configuration will look like this:

[image]

By considering the sum of opposite angles in the quadrilateral $BD'DB'$ and properties of cyclic quadrilaters, prove that $BD'DB'$ is cyclic.

Apply the intersecting secants theorem to $ABCD$ and to $BD'DB'$. Cancel the common factors in the two identities.

Apply the SAS similarity criterion to $\triangle APC$ and $\triangle D'PB'$. Now you have a transversal forming equal corresponding angles with $AC$ and $B'D'$.

Comment: Nice diagram and nice knowledge